# How to get relative cursor position to clicked element when appears click event in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to read position relative to clicked element `e.target` instead of `eventObject.pageX` and `eventObject.pageY`.

```
var eventObject = null;
$(document).click(function(e){
    eventObject = e;
    //how to get position relative to e.target ??
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:?

```
 var posX = $(this).position().left, posY = $(this).position().top;
 alert((e.pageX - posX) + ' , ' + (e.pageY - posY));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods of getting the position of an element depending on what you want.

This returns the position relative to the *element's parent*

```
$(eventObject.target).position().top;
$(eventObject.target).position().left;
```

And this is for the position relative to the *document*

```
$(eventObject.target).offset().top;
$(eventObject.target).offset().left;
```

The implementation differs depending on the position the element has (absolute or relative)

Answer (score 0):

```
var targetRelativeX = eventObject.pageX - eventObject.target.offsetLeft;
var targetRelativeY = eventObject.pageY - eventObject.target.offsetTop;
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it can your [see here](https://codepen.io/thamtucity/pen/EoKJyw)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var x = $("p").position();
        alert("Top position: " + x.top + " Left position: " + x.left);
    });
});
```